# How do I correctly export and import a plain JS file into another JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, keyboard-events

I need to export and import a plain js file to work keyboard navigation correctly.
I am following the example here,and using import and export pattern of ES5 but it is not linking one js file to another.
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html#
This is my codepen.io link
https://codepen.io/ankita-sharma-the-flexboxer/project/editor/DzdmBE

```
module.exports = PopupMenu;
var myModule = require('./popuplinks');
```

Comment: does this answer of your question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of exporting and importing JavaScript modules, in the past, we were using CommonJS modules which are in a format you've presented, they can be used in following way.

```js
// module.js
const myModule = "something"
module.exports = myModule
// And then if you want to import in another file, you're using following sentence.
const module = require("./module")
```

Actually we're using ES6-like imports, you can read about them at MDN, I'm attaching a small sample of ES6+ export.

```js
// module.js
const myModule = "Something"
export { myModule }
// And then
import {myModule} from './module'
```

Actually you should read [post that will resolve your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Do i need to use call module() after the require statement?
const module = require("./module");
module();

Comment: Also I am calling one js file init method into another js file after creating object from the constructor of that file. which seems to be not working after using import , export also.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html#
Please see the JS files here.

Comment: According to your code... You're importing file ("module") that don't exist in your foler, and obiviously nothing happens because doesn't exist.

Comment: Additionally @AnkitaSharma you don't import your scripts to HTML file and that can be potential problem with your code.

Comment: though im using correct import, export method , I think the init method means the constructor of one js file does not get called from another JS file, thats why I am not able to see the exact output as mentioned in w3 site in my codepen. How can i resolve that?

Comment: If you can please push this code to your GitHub or something because your Codepen is read-only and I cannot change anything.